# C# Replace &lt; with < in a html file

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, interop

I'm trying to make a word export function, but my content has html tags. I put this content in the html file, they replace < with `&lt;`, that is not what I want.

Can someone help me with this?

I use office interop word and here is the code that I use now:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Document doc = app.Documents.Open(FileName: @"C:\Users\example\Documents\Template.docx", ReadOnly: false);
app.Selection.Find.Execute("<Index>");
app.Selection.TypeText("<h1>hello</h1>");

doc.SaveAs2(@"C:\Users\krisb\Documents\voorbeeld.html", FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatWebArchive);
doc.Close();

Document doc1 = app.Documents.Open(FileName: @"C:\Users\example\Documents\voorbeeld.html", ReadOnly: false);
app.Selection.Find.Execute("&lt;");
app.Selection.TypeText("<");
app.Selection.Find.Execute("&gt;");
app.Selection.TypeText(">");

doc1.SaveAs2(@"C:\Users\example\Documents\template.docx", FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
doc1.Close();

Document doc2 = app.Documents.Open(FileName: @"C:\Users\example\Documents\kristemplate.docx", ReadOnly: false);
doc2.SaveAs2(@"C:\Users\example\Documents\kristemplate.pdf", FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);

app.Quit();`
```

Comment: _" they replace < with <"_?

Comment: no, if I put my html in my html file the replace < with &lt;

Comment: Then correct your question in that part.

Comment: o srry i will correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word is not a HTML editor, so you cannot tell it to use specific HTML tags directly. Word can only *import* and *export* HTML files. Internally, the Word object model treats them as Word documents.

What *might* work is to insert `"Hello"` and **format it in such a way that the HTML export will render it as h1**. I don't know if that is possible at all, but formatting your text as a "Heading 1" might be a good guess.

Alternatively, if you need to modify the generated HTML directly, you should

- export the file as HTML first, and *then*
- open it as a text file in C# and do your replacements.